# Bing Maps Api clear a layer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bing-maps

I have a page that works well it loads a Bing Map and creates a layer which is then filled with Polygons.  I then need to reload the JSON data that makes the polygons and this again works, however the data is then added to another layer so appears over the top.  I have tried to delete the layer, clear the layer etc etc but nothing seems to work.

Any idea please.

This is the function that does it all...

```
        function AddData() {

        dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();

        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {
            var featureCollection = Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.read(json, {
                polygonOptions: {
                    strokeColor: 'LightSkyBlue',
                    strokeThickness: 2
                }
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < featureCollection.length; i++) {
                var fillColour = featureCollection[i].metadata.FillColor;
                featureCollection[i].setOptions({ fillColor: fillColour });

                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(featureCollection[i], 'click', displayClickBox);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(featureCollection[i], 'mouseover', displayMouseOverBox);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(featureCollection[i],'mouseout', displayMouseOut);
                dataLayer.add(featureCollection[i], 0);
            }
            map.layers.insert(dataLayer);
        });
    }

        var getJson = function () {
        var onContentComplete = function (response) {
            //Load the JSON data into the local variable for use latter in the project...
            json = response.data;
            //load the map now that we have the polygon data...
            AddData();
        };

        var onError = function (reason) {
            //An error has occured so display a message to the user...
            $scope.error = "Server communication error please try again...";
            //Log the error to the console for admin debug...
            console.log(reason.data);
        };

        //Load the JSON for the map polygons into memory ready for display...
        $http.get("../JSON/MapData.json")
            .then(onContentComplete, onError);
    }
```

As I have said I have tried to clear the layer first using

```
dataLayer.clear();
```

But that seems to do nothing.

Help please as I have been working at this for hours now.

Thanks

Cliff.

Comment: The problem is not very clear to me. What do you mean by "appears over the top"? Over the top of what - the map? Shouldn't it appear on top of the map? What are the current and wanted situations? (screenshots might help)

Comment: The layers are on top of each other. There should be just one layer and I have an Alpha set of 0.3 so you can see the map below the polygon.  However as the function repeats it loads another layer above the last and the map gets progressively darker with each new layer. I just want one layer not multiple.

Comment: Can you please add the invocation of addData, as it sounds like addData is working perfectly as it should - but is called more than once with the same polygons (the same json object which holds the polygons).

Comment: et_l justed added sorry had to rush and catch a flight yesterday, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's helpful - but not complete. There is still no invocation there. Can you please add the part where `getJson()` appears? In the current code you just defined the function but haven't invoked it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the sounds of things you want all data to render in a single layer, but instead it is rendering two or more layers. This happens because you are creating a new instance of dataLayer every time the AddData function is called. Additionally, this overwrites the local variable for dataLayer and thus you lose the reference to the original layer that you are trying to clear/delete. If you want to clear or delete the layer, do that before initializing the new layer. Try adding the following to the top of your AddData function:

```
if(dataLayer){
   map.layers.remove(dataLayer);
}
```

Alternatively, reuse the layer by clearing it if it exists of or creating it if it doesn't:

```
if(dataLayer){
    dataLayer.clear();
}else{
    dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer();
}
```

Comment: From the discussion in the comments of the question it sounds to me like he is using the same data again and again (he wrote that the same polygon gets darker and darker because of the added layers). So I would suggest seeing where is the invocation first - it either doesn't need to be called more than once, or alternatively - if it's called every time a polygon is added to the `json` object for example, I would argue that removing or clearing the layer is a waste - as he is about to use the same data. Instead the function should be changed to ADD only the new data (polygons).